# How to DRY up this bootstrap modal from grid records in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a working bootstrap modal that is triggered from a record in a grid to capture small bits of information and post back for that record.

The way it is setup currently although working means the modal is rendered internally for each line in the grid, feels ugly but I can't see how to clean this up.

So, if I have 100 records I'll get 100 potential modals in the rendered code.
What I would like to do is have a single rendering of the modal and pass the relevant details to the modal.

In the view I have this happening:

```
    <% requests.each do |r| %>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#declineModal">
            Decline
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <%= render :partial => "decline_modal", :locals => { :r => r } %>
    <% end %>
```

the partial for the modal is here:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="declineModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="declineModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Decline Leave Request</h4>
      </div>
      <%= form_tag decline_leave_request_path(r), method: :get, :class => "form-horizontal" do %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= label_tag 'reason', 'Reason for Declining', :class => 'control-label' %>
          <%= text_field_tag :reason, params[:reason], :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <%= submit_tag "Submit Reason", name: nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**==== UPDATE 1 - NEW APPROACH ====**

Ok, here's what I have working now, I'm not sure if this is 100% correct but it is working and I am a lot happier about it.

in the view now I have this (only change is trigger some js on click):

```
    <% requests.each do |r| %>
      <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#declineModal" onclick='updateModal(#{record.id});'>
            Decline
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <%= render :partial => "decline_modal", :locals => { :r => r } %>
    <% end %>
```

I have updated the modals now to only be in the form once and removed reference to the model directly, as well as giving the form a name:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="declineModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="declineModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Decline Leave Request</h4>
      </div>
      <%= form_tag decline_leave_request_path(0), method: :get, :class => "form-horizontal", id: 'declineForm' do %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= label_tag 'reason', 'Reason for Declining', :class => 'control-label' %>
          <%= text_field_tag :reason, params[:reason], :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <%= submit_tag "Submit Reason", name: nil, class: "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

now all the work is done in the js
to update the modal id's when clicking the relevant buttons:

```
function updateModal(id){
  window.modal_id.value = id;
}
```

and register a handler for the modal form being shown to update the form action:

```
$('#declineModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  id = window.modal_id.value;
  var action = "/decline_leave_request/" + id;
  $("#declineForm").attr("action", action);      
})
```

Comment: I am not familiar with ruby. but the trick is in javascripts not in the server framework. just create a variable in js that changes when the user opens the modal, this variable should be your model of the record is being edited

Comment: @bto.rdz Ok, I think I have this working as suggested (more or less), have updated the Q with the new approach (all working fine). Thanks for the tip